# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS fails to boot

Tags: 14.04

I have Ubuntu 14.04 installed on a Lenovo G580 laptop, and I am no longer able to boot it. I tried recovery mode normal boot and failsafeX but it still fails. When I just go through the normal start process, everything seems normal: I see the five dots cycling red-white, then a few lines of text, which the last line is 'Restoring Resolver State' ... and then a blinking cursor.

I also tried to see if I could fix the problem using Ubuntu 14.04 Live disk, but it doesn't recognize the existing install. I am also not able to access the existing files and folders when in Tyy Ubuntu mode. But I can access my files and folders via tty or root from the recovery menu.

Any ideas?

update: solved by by reinstalling 14.04 LTS which preserved /home... See [Ubuntu 14.04 boots to black screen after upgrade from 13.10 - no display, problem seems to be X connected](https://askubuntu.com/questions/477370/ubuntu-14-04-boots-to-black-screen-after-upgrade-from-13-10-no-display-proble?rq=1) & https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuReinstallation for how to reinstall without losing your home folder

Thanks.

Comment: You can probably access the files from a USB Linux distro like Slax if you have a spare USB lying around. That way you might be able to save your key files and then do a fresh install. Next time make sure you back up lots! :)

Answer (score 0):

I found the guidance in this link helpful:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xeH28tVaTwo

The basic repair presented is:

1. Open a virtual console by pressing CTRL+ALT+F2 (I am not using a GUI, so I logged in using PuTTY)
2. Log in
3. Execute **sudo apt-get -f install**
4. Execute **sudo shutdown -r now**

Repeat steps 1-4 as as necessary.

You might try interspersing step 3 with **sudo apt-get update** and **sudo apt-get upgrade** until you get the desired results